# Displaying keyboard shortcut with Ext JS button

Tags: extjs, buttongroup, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a buttongroup with several buttons, each having a keyboard shortcut associated with it.

How can I also indicate the keyboard shortcut along with the button text also, on the button? While other option like tooltip is available, I want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend the button and alter the renderTpl so that you can add your shortcut txt into it and float it right. I've done this for a menuItem the following way:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.menu.ShortcutItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Item',
    alias: 'widget.shortcutitem',
    shortcutText: '', 
    renderTpl: [
        '<tpl if="plain">',
            '{text}',
        '<tpl else>',
            '<a id="{id}-itemEl" class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu-item-link" href="{href}" <tpl if="hrefTarget">target="{hrefTarget}"</tpl> hidefocus="true" unselectable="on">',
                '<img id="{id}-iconEl" src="{icon}" class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu-item-icon {iconCls}" />',
                '<span id="{id}-textEl" class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu-item-text" <tpl if="arrowCls">style="margin-right: 17px;"</tpl> >{text}</span>',
                '<span class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu-item-text shortcutitem-shrtTxt">{shortcutText}</span>', 
                '<img id="{id}-arrowEl" src="{blank}" class="{arrowCls}" />',
            '</a>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],
    beforeRender: function (ct, pos) {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me.renderData, {
            shortcutText: me.shortcutText
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And the css:

```
/* Shortcut menu item */
.shortcutitem-shrtTxt
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 7px;
}
```